# Mozilla focus after focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I am trying to make my code work targeting the 14 year unfixed bug in Mozzila which fails to focus back on the input. I have found in multiple places (most of the top 20 results in google `mozilla focus not working`) that setting a timeout for the focus will do the trick. However this is not working in any browser for me even tho it is the "official" (everyone says it worked for them) way to deal with this problem.

I have a simple `focusout` event targetting input with id `test`.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#test', function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(this).focus();
    }, 500);
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMqW7/)**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function changes the scope, so `this` isn't what you think it is, inside the timeout `this` is actually the window, as that's the natural scope of `window.setTimeout`

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#test', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).focus();
    }, 500);
});
```

As a sidenote, why wouldn't you let the user focus anything else than the input, it seems like horrible UX.

Comment: Luckily I only spent two hours with this and not the whole day! That was fast. Feeling so stupid that I overlooked this. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Now you'll remember it the next time, new function = new scope.

Comment: I just noticed your last sentence and, don't worry, the idea behind this is way deeper (the example in jsfiddle is made to be as simple as it was possible) and does nothing horrible, trust me on this, hehe :P